# Postgres group by having at least 1 row with status='started'

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, having-clause

I need to perform a group by and only including if at least one observation matches the constraint. Like I have tried to describe below.

```
SELECT {some variables}
FROM my_table
GROUP BY A
HAVING {at least 1 row with status='started'}
```

My initial guess to replace was "*at least 1 row with status='started'*" was "*bool_or(status='started')*". Which doesn't work.

Do any of you have a sugestion?

EDIT:

```
SELECT {some variables}
FROM my_table
GROUP BY A
HAVING bool_or(status='started');
```

Works fine. The reason it not work for me, was that I used the wrong quotation mark. Thanks for your help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`having bool_or(status = 'started'`) is a nice option in Postgres, and probably your best pick here.

It is actually equivalent to:

```
having max( (status = 'started')::int ) = 1
```

For the sake of completness: in standard SQL, you would phrase this with a `case` expression:

```
having max(case when status = 'started' then 1 end) = 1
```

Comment: or in modern standard SQL: `having count(*) filter (where status = 'started') > 0`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: is that part of the ANSI standard now? I am asking because Postgres is the only database that I know that supports such syntax.

Comment: Yes, it was added in SQL:2006

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: OK, thanks for information. It's a shame that such document are not freely available... And a shame also that database products do not put real effort in implementing such valuable part of it!